# Where can I find a movie dataset with plots and genres?

Tags: nlp, dataset

I'm planning to make a movie genre classifier based on movie plots. I'm looking for a database which includes movies plots and genres. I tried to get IMDB's own dataset but it's paid also doesn't have movie plots. Any idea would be appreciated, thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a blog post a while go where I used an IMDB corpus, the corpus is still available, and contains, for each movie a plot and the possible genres that it matches. You can get it here:

http://davidsbatista.net/blog/2017/04/01/document_classification/

Answer (score 1):

CMU Movie Summary Corpus
This page provides links to a dataset of movie plot summaries and associated metadata. This data was collected by David Bamman, Brendan O'Connor, and Noah Smith at the Language Technologies Institute and Machine Learning Department at Carnegie Mellon University.
Try This : http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ark/personas/

Answer (score 0):

IMDB has not been paying nice and putting DMCA takedowns for their data on other sites, so the good people at Kaggle created this https://www.kaggle.com/tmdb/tmdb-movie-metadata (powered by TMDB).

Here's the example kernel for the TMDB metadata on https://www.kaggle.com/sohier/getting-imdb-kernels-working-with-tmdb-data/

The TMDB API can be also accessed from https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api

Answer (score 0):

quanteda has a dataset containing movies and reviews, could it be helpful?

```
require(quanteda, warn.conflicts = FALSE, quietly = TRUE)
data(data_corpus_movies, package = "quanteda.corpora")
```